# What's an "inline query"?

Tags: postgresql

According to the [currently accepted answer to this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17131/99007) a partial solution to an efficiency problem was to "inline" the query. I can't tell what that is, I can't ask in comments (too little rep) and Googling 'postgresql inline query' isn't very decisive ([some seem to think it's synonymous w/"subquery" but others don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/308456/1676382)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the FROM clause below, the subquery acts as a table:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, name FROM users)
```

That subquery is called an inline view. So in this case you are not directly selecting rows from a table, but from an "inline view".
 From your first link it seems that the user created an actual view, which you can do from a query. More information over here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html

But it seems that Erwin thinks it might be a better idea, performance wise in that specific case, to "inline the query" from the view. Or in other words, not by first creating a view but use inline views like I did.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So... "inlining the view as a subquery" would have been the pedantic way of putting it? ;)

Comment: Yes, "inlining the view as a subquery" is one way of putting it.